# Php Script Refuses to Send to Outlook.com

Tags: php, email

This seems like a reoccurring problem with outlook.com for many individuals.

My script below works with `@college.edu`, `@gmail.com` , but on outlook.com - it refuses to reach even the `junk` folder, nevermind the `inbox` - how can I modify it to fix it?

I have checked my sender domain to ensure it is not blacklisted.

**Script:**

```
<?php
$doraccount = 'noreply@mydomain.com';

$pathwayurl = $_POST['pathway_url'];

$to = $_POST['email_address'];
$subject = "Path Share";
#message for email
$message = '<html><body><div style=width:362px;display:block;margin:0% auto;>';
$message .= "<img src='http://domain.com/sites/default/files/togo3.gif' alt='my site' /></div>";
#$message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
#$message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'></tr>";
$message .= '<div><p>Thank you for using Pathway tool. We have provided you with a link to the below.  Please check out our other programs and offerings on the <a href="http://www.oursite.com">our site website</a></p>';
$message .= "<br /><br /><strong>link:</strong> <tr><td>" . $pathwayurl ."</div>";
$message .= '<div><p>The Team<br /><a href="mailto:info@domain.com">info@domain.com</a></p></div>';;
$message .= "</body></html>";

$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "From: " . $doraccount . PHP_EOL;

if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
    echo "<div style=text-align:center;>
            <img src='http://domain.com/sites/default/files/togo3.gif' alt='domain' /> <br />
            <strong>The email was successfully sent.</strong>
            <br> Redirecting you back to the pathway. 
         </div>";
    header('Refresh: 3;url='.$pathwayurl);
    #echo $message;


} else {
    echo "The email was NOT sent.";
}
?>
```

Logs showing:
**Unfortunately, messages from
    xx.xx.xx.xx weren't sent. Please contact your Internet service provider
    since part of their network is on our block list.**

Comment: Have you checked blacklist sites online to make sure that your domain isn't blacklisted?

Comment: Yes I have done that.

Comment: It may be worth trying a proper mailer library, like SwiftMailer - my guess is they add headers and other things, by default, that reduce problems of this kind.

Comment: Check error log, syslog, postfix/sendmail log...

Comment: Regardless, my guess is that your mail is being refused by outlook.com. Have you looked at error logs?

Comment: `mail()` is nearly useless junk. use a proper mailer (phpmailer, swiftmailer), both of which offer far greater diagnostic capabilities. and also check your smtp server's logs, see what happens after PHP hands over the email. php/mail's job is to walk your letter down to the street corner and toss it into the mailbox. you need to check what happened in the rest of the postal system as well.

Comment: From personal experience, Microsoft has extremely stringent spam filters, and from your most recent edit, you are quite definitely blocked.

Comment: Please see my updated log ... how do I get unblocked @sjagr ?

Comment: Assuming you actually have care and control of the IP address that you're sending email from, you fill out this [godawful form](https://support.live.com/eform.aspx?productKey=edfsmsbl3&ct=eformts&scrx=1) and twiddle your thumbs for about a week while Microsoft very very very slowly removes you from their blacklists. Don't expect to get delisted if, for example, you are running this server on your personal computer from a home ISP. Similarly, if you are in a shared environment, you will have to contact your webhosting provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You redefine your header a few times. You want the following:

```
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" . PHP_EOL;
$headers = "From: " . $doraccount . "\r\n" . PHP_EOL;

$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "From: domain<$from>" . PHP_EOL;
```

First you set the `$header` to `MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL`, then add `"Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" . PHP_EOL`. Then you overwrite all previous data with `"MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "From: domain<$from>" . PHP_EOL;`. The next line you clear the `$header`, and set it to `"MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL`, followed by `"Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" . PHP_EOL` and `"From: domain<$from>" . PHP_EOL`. In the end, your header is as following:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n
From: domain<$from>\r\n
```

You overwrite your old `From` header, so this might make Outlook think it's a spam mail and blacklist it immediatly (so it doesn't even reach the spam folder)

Comment: Good point, although, for some reason that didnt copy in right. I only have mime-version, content-type, and From declared once. See updated.

Comment: But your new `From` header is wrong too. Replace that line with the following: `$headers .= "From: " . $doraccount . PHP_EOL;`

Comment: Please see updated code including your suggestion and the **log** output.